# Issuing a warning at compile time?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, rust-macros

I want to issue a warning at compile time, perhaps from a macro. It should not be silenceable by `cap_lints`. My current use case is feature deprecation, but there's other possible uses for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This currently isn't possible in stable Rust. However, there is an unstable feature, [procedural macro diagnostics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54140), which provides this functionality for procedural macros, via the [`Diagnostic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Diagnostic.html#method.warning) API.

To emit a compiler warning from inside a procedural macro, you would use it like this:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_diagnostic)]

use proc_macro::Diagnostic;

Diagnostic::new()
    .warning("This method is deprecated")
    .emit();
```

To associate the warning with a specific token span, you'd use `spanned_warning` instead. This makes the warning output show the relevant source tokens underlined along with the message.